# Input a ASCII text file / Convert every character it to ASCII value in Python

Tags: python, list, ascii

I am totally beginner in programmaing, so please forgive my mistakes.

I am trying to create a Python program which takes as input a ASCII text file, then converts every single character in its ASCII number value and keeps only the odd results of them. Finally, I must visyallize my exports for each character, using * as bars with percentage (See picture)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXtDe.png).

I have managed to go this far,

```
f = open(r"c:\python\7_ASCII\Sample.txt", "r")
result = ' '.join((str(ord(x)) for x in f))
print(f)
```

which gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 320 found
```

I've tried many methods such as list comprehensions but the error insists in appearing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Read the file into a string. Iterate through the string and perform `ord()` on each character.

Comment: Each of `f` is a string representing each line of the input file, you will need to iterate through each character of the string and convert that to ASCII value, that means, you are missing a second loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are not reading your text file.  To do so you have to use `f.read()`:

```
f = open(r"c:\python\7_ASCII\Sample.txt", "r")
my_text = f.read()
print(my_text)
```

With this you can iterate over your text and apply the logic.  However, bear in mind that you can open your files using `with`:

```
with open(r"c:\python\7_ASCII\Sample.txt", "r") as reader:
    print(reader.read())
```